Refused to connect error after refreshing sandbox with MFA as high assurance
In my production org, my session settings is as follows :

Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated = TRUE
Lock sessions to the domain in which they were first used = TRUE
High Assurance = Multi-Factor Authentication

After refreshing sandbox, these settings will be copied to sandbox.
I, as admin will try go Permission Sets/ Session Settings & save/  where this "Identity Verification" page will be displayed :

I tried pressing back, nothing happens. When pressing "Register", an error page will be shown " refused to connect." (see screenshot)

Is there a best practice/pre/post deployment step I'm missing?
Things I tried so far but didn't work :

Logout, Login
Login via incognito window
Login via Google Chrome
Login via Microsoft edge

It unexpectedly worked when using Firefox :
Firefox at least allowed me to view using classic and then register for Salesforce Authenticator 
Why is it only working for Firefox, not GC or Microsoft Edge?
